# How to share internet from Win10 laptop with PiZero (no WiFi) headlessly using USB cable?

Tags: networking, ssh, pi-zero, dhcp

I am trying to share internet using USB cable to Raspberry Pi Zero (without WiFi module). I have used the latest documentation and advices but no matter what approach I attempt, PiZero cannot `ping` any websites and they all result in `Temporary failure in name resolution`.

I am going to describe all of the steps I have done so far and provide the outputs. I am going to start with devices I use.

1. Windows 10 Machine, Laptop which is connected to internet using WiFi.
2. Raspberry PiZero (without WiFi module)
3. USB Cable

I am connecting 1 - 3 - 2 as shown in this picture:

[image]

**Steps done so far**

I started by flashing micro sd card and installing the latest lite OS which is Raspberry Pi OS Lite  (2022-09-06 Debian Bullseye) using the Raspberry Pi Imager. I used advanced settings and selected to enable hostname, ssh, username and password, wireless LAN (although I this is redundant given it has no WiFi module), and locale.

[image]

Once the image was written into the SD card, I opened the OS location and edited the following files:

- config.txt and appended the line `'dtoverlay=dwc2'` at the end
- cmdline.txt and appended the line `'modules-load=dwc2,g_ether'` into cmdline.txt after '`rootwait`'

I then added `ssh.txt` file to enable ssh. (Until I did this the ssh would not work and I was bit puzzled what the setting on Pi Imager was useful for).

I then ejected the card and inserted it into the Pi. On the Windows 10 side, I have installed the RNDIS driver, my approach here was to download the driver directly from [Microsoft Catalogue](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=USB%20RNDIS%20Gadget) and manually update the USB driver. By default Win 10 did not recognised the driver. Once this was done, PiZero would be recognised:

[image]

At this stage, I would ensure everything was restarted / rebooted and then connected the PiZero into the computer using the USB port on the PiZero. Interestingly some micro usb cables did not work, the one on the picture was the only one which did manage to connect to the Pi.

I tried connecting using VS Code and Putty (both had identical results) and I am describing the VS Code approach here.

Using VS Code and Powershell terminal I:

`ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` into the Pi. This is okay.

I proceed to edit: `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
interface usb0
static ip_address=192.168.0.15/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

[image]

I was conservative and used ip_address that was suggested by default in `dhcpcd.conf`. I saved the file and rebooted the pi.

I set up sharing of the internet from my WiFi to PiZero:

[image]

I set up appropriate IP address on PiZero RNDIS that was set up on `dhcpcd.conf`:

[image]

I log in back into the RaspberryPi, at this stage I assume everything should work and I should be able to connect to the internet and test the following:
`ifconfig -a`

[image]

I test internet connection:

```
sudo ping www.raspberrypi.com
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping -c3 google.com
```

[image]

No response from the internet.

I have looked couple of other tutorials, I also tried to install Bonjour but have not manage to resolve how to connect / ping internet from Pi. I am considering purchasing other usb cable but I would appreciate help to confirm if any of the above has mistakes. Happy to provide further information but I am not sure where I could have gone wrong.

Comment: This is a problem with Windows - NOTHING to do with Pi. Can you ping the Windows machine?

Comment: PS Why are you making life more difficult by attempting to set static ip_address?

Comment: **Ad 1:** Thanks for a pointer, it seems Pi cannot reach out to the laptop. `ping: ThinkPad: Temporary failure in name resolution`. Pinging WiFi IP address showed `3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2094ms` 
**Ad 2:** I guess you refer to the `sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf`, would you suggest to only set the first line? That is, `interface usb0` and leave the rest out.

Comment: If you don't understand networking, it's going to be difficult for you. **Assuming** you've sussed your local network correctly as `192.168.0` you have a valid route to the *gateway* (192.168.0.1). Now you need to add a route from the gateway to the Pi Zero. That route must go *through* your Windows host. FWIW, I did [something similar with a pocket beagle](https://github.com/seamusdemora/EmbeddedJungle/blob/master/ExperimentsWithPocketBeagle.md)

Comment: @Seamus Thanks for the comment. I am not sure how the first statement 'If you don't understand networking, it's going to be difficult for you' will help to resolve the issue as it doesn't suggest any particular resources, approach, or methods. However, the latter, this does help thanks, I will have a look and check if it is really a valid route.

Comment: @gofraidh: The first statement was *prepatory*... like when the dentist says, "This is going to hurt a bit." Get it? If it doesn't help, feel free to disregard it.